# Update new added columns in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, sql-update, acid, bigdata

I have been trying to make updates to an orc table in hive which is bucketed and also `set transactional=true` property. The normal update works great but as soon as I alter the table and add a new column e.g. `column_added_5`, and try to update `column_added_5` the statement executes but the column does not get updated.

Any help/directions is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that one way is:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS SELECT column1,column2,column3, ... "default_value" as column_added_5 FROM your_table_name;

DROP TABLE your_table_name;

ALTER TABLE new_table_name RENAME TO your_table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMNS ( column_added_5 STRING COMMENT 'Column 5');
```